# How do I edit .sql file in phpmyadmin via ssh terminal on MAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terminal, amazon-lightsail

I am currently using Amazon Lighsail for my Wordpress site. I have a fresh Wordpress install on my Lightsail account but would like to upload my old mysql tables from my current site to phpmyadmin.

I have ssh-ed into the terminal and have done `cd apps/phpmyadmin/` but I am not seeing my wp_ tables that I need to replace. How do I access this?

I tried the following command to do ssh port forwarding but it didnt work:
`ssh bitnami@xx.xxx.xx.xxx -R 8080:127.0.0.1:80` (with the x's being real numbers)

Any idea on how I can upload my current .sql.zip file to Wordpress AWS Lighsail using SSH?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your creating an SSH tunnel to send web traffic through.  You create a tunnel in your terminal, then Open a web browser and point it at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin`

Comment: that's what I am trying to do by porting it forward @MisterSmith. Right now when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin` i get DNS error despite having my AWS VM running

Comment: Have you confirmed if phpmyadmin is actually running/available from the server? Login to server with SSH and run `netstat -tln` to view listening ports - 127.0.0.1:80 should appear in the list? If so, use `curl http://127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin` to make a web request from the terminal - you will get the HTML page or a connection failed. This will prove everything is working remotely. (If it deosnt work try ports 8080 and 8888 as well)
can you post any output/error from ssh command? (enable verbose output with `-v`).